# RegisterType not in Autofac 2.3.2?

Tags: autofac

Using AutoFac 2.3.2, I am trying to do the following:

```
var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SomeDependency>().As<IDependency>();
```

RegisterType is not there. Not seeing it with intellisense, compiler doesn't know it's there. Looking in the help shows that the RegisterType method is an extension method. Is there something I'm missing? Why is this extension method not showing up?

I'm using VS2010, attempting the above code in a test project and a web application project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `use Autofac` or use the static method directly.

```
use Autofac;
namespace X
{
   builder.RegisterType<MyType>();
}
```

or

```
Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterType<MyType>(builder);
```

Comment: Thanks! I added "using Autofac;" and now the extension methods are there. DUH! I should have thought of that.